# Question regarding difference between Bases and Local Bases (Topology)

Tags: general-topology

I am trying to *really* understand the difference between Bases and Local Bases in Topology. Below is the question I *posed* for myself, however, I am having trouble really seeing through it.

**Question:** Consider the Standard Topology $(\mathbb{R}_{std.})$ and let $x \in \mathbb{R}$. Consider the set
$\mathscr{B}_x = \{(x - \epsilon, x + \epsilon) : \epsilon > 0\}$. Is $\mathscr{B}_x$ a Base for $\mathbb{R}_{std.}$? Is $\mathscr{B}_x$ a Local Base at $x$?

I know that the answers are no and yes, respectively. However, I am having trouble seeing *exactly* why. I will explain where my thinking has led me...I know that $\mathscr{B}_x$ is a Local Base at $x$, since, given some $U \in \mathbb{R}_{std.}$ if $x \in U$, then by def. of being open in $\mathbb{R}_{std.}$, for any $x \in U$, $\exists \epsilon > 0: x \in (x-\epsilon, x + \epsilon) \subseteq U$. Since
$(x-\epsilon, x + \epsilon) \in \mathscr{B}_x$ we have that $\mathscr{B}_x$ is a Local Base at $x$. Now, I still need to show that $\mathscr{B}_x$ is not a Base for $\mathbb{R}_{std.}$. By way of contradiction, assume that $\mathscr{B}_x$ is a Base for $\mathbb{R}_{std.}$ and let $U \in \mathbb{R}_{std.}$. Then, by def. of being open in $\mathbb{R}_{std.}$, we must have that $\forall p \in U$, $\exists \epsilon > 0 : 
p \in (p - \epsilon, p + \epsilon) \subseteq U$. And from here I am just not sure how this leads to a contradiction.

I *somewhat* get why this leads to a contradiction, since, we only know that $\mathscr{B}_x$ "works" for $x$ and not every $p \in U$.

It would be best if someone could give me an actual example of this happening in $\mathbb{R}_{std.}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A base $\mathcal{B}$ for a topology $(X,\mathcal{T})$ can be characterised as a a collection of open sets such that

$$\forall O: \forall x \in O: \exists B \in \mathcal{B}: x \in B \subseteq O\tag{1}$$

Whereas for a local base at $x$ we need this condition to hold *only* for open sets that happen to contain $x$ and for that $x$ itself, so:

$$(\forall B \in \mathcal{B}: x \in B) \land \forall O: (x \in O) \to (\exists B \in \mathcal{B}: x \in B \subseteq O)\tag{2}$$

in which $x$ is a free variable (parameter).

So all sets in a local base at $x$ have to be open and contain $x$ (the first clause of $(2)$;  if we omit that then we have a so-called local *pseudo-base* at $x$) and we can alwyas find a member inside any other open neighbourhood of $x$. It does *not* say anything about other points of $X$ unequal to $x$, while $(1)$ is a global condition, which holds for all open sets and all their points.

So if $\mathcal{B}$ is a base, we can take all sets in $\mathcal{B}$ that contain some fixed $x$ and we always have a local base at $x$ that way.

And if we have a local base at $x$ for all $x$ separately, taking their union over all $x \in X$ gives us a base for the whole space. It's really quite natural.

Answer (score 0):

$\mathscr{B}_x$ is a collection dependent on $x\in\mathbb{R}$. So, did you want to ask "given $x\in\mathbb{R}$ is $\mathscr{B}_x$ a base for $\mathbb{R}?$" This is false because every open subset generated from $\mathscr{B}_x$ has to contain $x$. And we know there are other open subsets in $\mathbb{R}$.

But $\bigcup_{x\in\mathbb{R}}\mathscr{B}_x$ is indeed a base for $\mathbb{R}$.

And so $\mathscr{B}_x$ describes the topology of $\mathbb{R}$ locally, only around one, fixed $x\in\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Thank you, the one sentence you gave, "this is clearly false because every open subset generated from $\mathscr{B}_x$ has to contain $x$ ", cleared up my confusion!